# Prepending CDN url to all image references in grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I use a default grunt build, which replaces all image references with name+hash in the source code.
This was when I had all the images in same place as my index.html

Now I need to use CDN to store images. I used [grunt-aws-s3](https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/grunt-aws-s3) for uploading all images in my /images folder to CDN.

But how do I prepend all the image name references with my CDN URL?